# Simple python calculator converted from 3 to 2.7

Tags: python

I'm trying to get convert this from python 3 to 2.7 and I think I may have messed up with the indentation.  The shell provides an error message of:

```
line 20, if(operation == '+'), IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I'd like to keep the code as intact as possible but I cannot see the bug!  Ugh!

```
def add(num1, num2):
  return num1 + num2

def subtract(num1, num2):
  return num1 - num2

def multiply(num1, num2):
  return num1 * num2

def divide(num1, num2):
  return num1 / num2  

def main():
  operation = raw_input("What do you want ot do (+,-,*,/): ")
  if(operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '*' and operation != '/'):
    print "you must enter a valid operation"
  else:
    var1 = int(raw_input("Enter num1: "))
    var2 = int(raw_input("Enter num2: "))
        if(operation == '+'):
            print add(var1, var2)
        elif(operation == '-'):
            print sub(var1, var2)
        elif(operation == '*'):
            print mul(var1, var2)
        else(operation == '/'):
            print div(var1, var2)


main()
```

[image]

Comment: the `if`/`elif`/`else` lines below the `var2` assignment are indented, and shouldn't be.

Comment: "but I cannot see the bug! Ugh! " - in your own words, when you look at the code as it is posted: how much is line 20 indented? How much do you think it should be indented, and why? Same questions for line 19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends using [4 space indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id12), here is the code of your calculator reformatted to 4 spaces:

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def subtract(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

def multiply(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

def divide(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2  

def main():
    operation = raw_input("What do you want ot do (+,-,*,/): ")
    if(operation != '+' and operation != '-' and 
       operation != '*' and operation != '/'):
        print "you must enter a valid operation"
    else:
        var1 = int(raw_input("Enter num1: "))
        var2 = int(raw_input("Enter num2: "))
        if(operation == '+'):
            print add(var1, var2)
        elif(operation == '-'):
            print sub(var1, var2)
        elif(operation == '*'):
            print mul(var1, var2)
        else:
            print div(var1, var2)


main()
```

The IndentationError exception on compilation, happened because you had the 20th line and those appearing after it overindented.

After that I found the else (else(operation == '/'):) which is invalid, because it does not need a condition, I replaced it by and else, because at this stage we are really sure the operation is '/'.

**Side note:**

As @Jkdc proposes we can also check operator strings using this approach, which is more readable, in my opinion:

```
if(operation not in ['+', '-', '*', '/']):
    print "you must enter a valid operation"
else:
    #Rest of the code
```

Basically, it checks if the operation string is not found in the list of operators, instead of comparing them separately on 4 conditions.

Comment: Just a side note, you can clean up: `if(operation != '+' and ...):` by changing it to: `if operation not in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:`

Comment: @Jkdc yes, you are right. I noticed that, but I wanted to stay as near as possible to the question code, anyways I will add it as a side note and credit it to you!! Thank you

Comment: Thank you!  I'm slowly learning the details! So I screwed up with the final else catch-all and indention.  Thanks!